# Flutter vs Kotin, which one is best for making online learning app?

Tags: flutter, kotlin, mobile

I made learning app with **angularjs** and want to make it in mobile apps too. which one is good for me?
and I don't have any *android development knowledge*. I'm just starting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well actually it is a very broad topic. But I will try to keep it as simple as possible. For mobile development you must at least have the basic knowledge of programming i.e.

1. OOP
2. Data Structures (not very compulsory, but a plus)

Talking about Kotlin vs Flutter. First, you don't compare Native development with Cross platform development.

But, if you are starting with mobile development. I would recommend you to start `Flutter`. The development experience is way more `delightful` than any other language or framework. I've tried native android development using java, but Flutter is just next level!

Its easier and yes you can `develop a learning app using Flutter`.

Meanwhile, if you are looking to start Flutter here are few resources that you can use to get a kick start or you can also buy some course from Udemy.

1. [Flutter for Beginners in 2020](https://itnext.io/flutter-for-beginners-in-2020-b32e19676231?source=friends_link&sk=32d6c21eaec97d885981b57ee4f05e76)
2. [Things I wish I knew when I started Flutter](https://itnext.io/things-i-wish-i-knew-when-i-started-flutter-d43f09912449?source=friends_link&sk=f7c1733d51cbef16ac3255c4d402e3cb)

And don't worry they are `free links` so you don't need Medium Membership to read them.

Good Luck with your app! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think Flutter would be better option for you. It is based on widgets, and in my opinion, it's user friendly.